# IP address from headers (Gmail/outlook mobile app)

Tags: email, ip, gmail, header, outlook

My question isn't a duplicate. I know that the IP is leaked in the computer desktop version of outlook. But from I'm able to tell, the mobile version didn't leak it.
I need to make sure that I'm right and that the IP address wasn't leaked in the headers below in any form, for example, there's a ton of different numbers in the headers, maybe the location is encoded in one of them somehow?

Here's a header, names and email addresses are removed.

Can you get an IP or location from it?

```
Received: from BY5PR14MB3575.namprd14.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:1c5::24)

by CY8PR14MB5980.namprd14.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Sat, 11 Feb 2023

01:33:48 +0000

Received: from MW4PR03CA0286.namprd03.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:303:b5::21)

by BY5PR14MB3575.namprd14.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:1c5::24) with

Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,

cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6086.17; Sat, 11 Feb

2023 01:33:44 +0000

Received: from MW2NAM12FT044.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com

(2603:10b6:303:b5:cafe::b7) by MW4PR03CA0286.outlook.office365.com

(2603:10b6:303:b5::21) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,

cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6086.21 via Frontend

Transport; Sat, 11 Feb 2023 01:33:44 +0000

Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 209.85.219.54)

smtp.mailfrom=Gmail; dkim=pass (signature was verified)

header.d=http://gmail.com;dmarc=pass (http://gmail.com;dmarc=pass) action=none header.from=http://gmail.com;compauth=pass (http://gmail.com;compauth=pass)

reason=100

Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of gmail.com designates

209.85.219.54 as permitted sender) receiver=http://protection.outlook.com;

client-ip=209.85.219.54; helo=http://mail-qv1-f54.google.com; pr=C

Received: from mail-qv1-f54.google.com (209.85.219.54) by

MW2NAM12FT044.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.180.247) with Microsoft SMTP

Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id

15.20.6111.7 via Frontend Transport; Sat, 11 Feb 2023 01:33:44 +0000

Received: by mail-qv1-f54.google.com with SMTP id nd22so2183060qvb.1

for <Ne@s.com>; Fri, 10 Feb 2023 17:33:44 -0800 (PST)

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;

d=Gmail; s=20210112;

h=mime-version:content-language:accept-language:message-id:date

:thread-index:thread-topic:subject:to:from:from:to:cc:subject:date

:message-id:reply-to;

bh=oUD7h8Pd7JugwtYRQWBp0IID2L15elTs/tiIN+iv2JQ=;

b=XzLzqyXXS/5l77TdubF3rnDMF0tgjVrzzjvvXp5AnhBlM4FBFI+pJ7rgriGiOd5pk1

InctSZzXaT4MA/VhLqC2+ELHNof1Js1DU7LVf6DS93iMDhtcyQxaSIikWYj0CvaSEQ0X

u8H8od5MhjQVA6yGuMTA0NWMD5VTHINvUfo8iGyIXDEJfEvtjqK5BYXmHfETBLbWmckr

CjCp1AvOcAxD8vxw2piLZtHSAHPvS+RGnk7vel+TK0vaAesVlffi4F21gYuxofaAFQa7

o5n9i0u6n/XA5a7dWdPkWUUqJkAEjJ3L7kVuzzL6NBfQzNXhQXTpcAWNTJcMEOKdDglP

es7w==

X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;

d=http://1e100.net; s=20210112;

h=mime-version:content-language:accept-language:message-id:date

:thread-index:thread-topic:subject:to:from:x-gm-message-state:from

:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;

bh=oUD7h8Pd7JugwtYRQWBp0IID2L15elTs/tiIN+iv2JQ=;

b=RbZXUSaE18US4jjOvqVYI9JuzhAvLzS/jlvJ8WChb3SvBfoDdh9ahXwyEWOspxJ2m0

E5aCafN4FHfkJSdf5S6gLQ+/Is2TCMh1cguprxLafKee148Eg/XepS4LM02VarXdF7IG

wCt9jJzk04uZzFrn27NOGvnkKq5iJrfNCei+sacFQobSIhZqKFpResxTNxiOZ1diftxx

QI23qUjKxvHcpgWpsVmeeLp5TCxriQgJbbYZP/ush7CxCZeygA/SfWSmifLspg2YdSpY

cGE8Z7ElexmLrQtc4sIzm1LPlGDA7QB7nYC0IuoLZNi4zck3jpkl610yM6WRW46DE1zp

fSrA==

X-Gm-Message-State: AO0yUKUjr71TKhWxHvxO2DIeKQ00afzjuxA+UbVq/4A6/+8D3WisisA+

tmOF4MNIeW1jqsZikSAEbWUoXeABEPNs4Q==

X-Google-Smtp-Source: AK7set/ZW2udsgWLo0E0A+YlyySFa2bjpF7qIiNmqvSilKyTCXOKOvsPJ/l4/xd1y5mLLkRRkXgDtA==

X-Received: by 2002:a05:6214:2507:b0:56c:304:2220 with SMTP id gf7-20020a056214250700b0056c03042220mr34082412qvb.37.1676079222975;

Fri, 10 Feb 2023 17:33:42 -0800 (PST)

Return-Path: l01@gmail.com

Received: from IA1PR14MB5612.namprd14.prod.outlook.com ([2603:1036:207:807::5])

by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id v66-20020a37dc45000000b006fba0a389a4sm4764774qki.88.2023.02.10.17.33.42

for <e@ps.com>

(version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);

Fri, 10 Feb 2023 17:33:42 -0800 (PST)

From: kjjj <l@gmail.com>

To: jjjj jjjj <N@K.com>

Subject: jjjjj

Thread-Topic: jjjj

Thread-Index: AQHZPbjYP4XSEPzvtEeypk2/AM95SQ==

X-MS-Exchange-MessageSentRepresentingType: 1

Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2023 01:33:41 +0000

Message-ID:

<IA1PR14MB5612FCDEE7995800FB2D94FCA5DF9@IA1PR14MB5612.namprd14.prod.outlook.com>

Accept-Language: en-US

Content-Language: en-US

X-MS-Has-Attach:

X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

boundary="_000_IA1PR14MB5612FCDEE7995800FB2D94FCA5DF9IA1PR14MB5612namp_"

MIME-Version: 1.0

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 11 Feb 2023 01:33:44.2678

(UTC)

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:

b5989871-602f-4517-ec6c-08db0bd0037c

X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0

X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: c25a5e91-8c74-4fcf-bfe7-686c522b3737:0

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming

X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email

X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: MW2NAM12FT044:EE_|BY5PR14MB3575:EE_

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:

http://mw2nam12ft044.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com/
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous

X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: b5989871-602f-4517-ec6c-08db0bd0037c

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1

X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;

X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:

CIP:209.85.219.54;CTRY:US;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:mail-qv1-f54.google.com;PTR:mail-qv1-f54.google.com;CAT:NONE;SFS:(13230025)(451199018)(52536014)(82202003)(3480700007)(33656002)(1096003)(9686003)(7116003)(26005)(55016003)(356005)(564344004)(7696005)(5660300002)(76482006)(45080400002)(86362001)(336012)(73392003)(426003)(6916009)(8676002)(166002)(7596003)(7636003);DIR:INB;

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Feb 2023 01:33:44.2366

(UTC)

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: b5989871-602f-4517-ec6c-08db0bd0037c

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: c25a5e91-8c74-4fcf-bfe7-686c522b3737

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:

http://mw2nam12ft044.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com/
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet

X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BY5PR14MB3575

X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:03.8947872

X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.6086.020

X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:

ucf:0;jmr:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(910001)(944506478)(944626604)(920097)(930097);

X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:

=?us-ascii?Q?DgCft7287qrDfryb3BikySAZnbk8puYpkvCIe2B089WApGJ/L0bXvr7h3JNM?=

=?us-ascii?Q?TXkS6M/A3NCSODmdI0twnLcR+dpn8VIUlCiK4XlML7NwBL0sgMJyRoYv6TUi?=

=?us-ascii?Q?QKbxLGFl8dt6cu4PIpcZFuwyjiPo1rLmg1SwHz3uOtkDkYwjwsx/0Zqik3zG?=

=?us-ascii?Q?fFOXxTbXpsSzYE7dM3pYC8M4v/xdR5lKJY0Pa7r1qpgFGSOTJ99I3hvB2UHx?=

=?us-ascii?Q?e/lqdUdjNuxtabk0kDibUBt7fZcpHS/QzcS+f+kLQJwVBtdBoDG7vhL2J5wT?=

=?us-ascii?Q?tyTGkdCIrLCSPScQEIzmdICsUpb4aa1H3jVB6B6qW7n3UesRhCvZzijJgPcy?=

=?us-ascii?Q?ew5n64Y25iKbxFAC0c0z5H1ZHQQwqf6UQsEX+6j9zohSDvHGxTpVxbBdj8gM?=

=?us-ascii?Q?LgVsAwAn9EeHoLsjytxITXuvvFqe9WUTGMZ5IVukly3G39811Su1J8AVJg0F?=

=?us-ascii?Q?rIhniackEd2a891J6f/uED1KYWymztdwcBhc4upFPRURE6Y+rEWJ1iIT/EqA?=

=?us-ascii?Q?IAZiBpkbLfcPtWWsyLKF5tASngPUsWqJEKc3riZ2GVHiGEYYSw7AGv3DskDH?=

=?us-ascii?Q?G2kt+Yq0griAfmBD7fX/7pnNCqFrOnQv+HCvtxx4V0N165fkIM9gZDeYlTBW?=

=?us-ascii?Q?nQwdux92y27J8pgEdUEIyQs8XmO9CHYgEwO6na/vT99iKBSef8NU2Gxhto2u?=

=?us-ascii?Q?2LweIHQqSch1ZZkMVqvoNFt0K3RsNIcYASUPVtJqi8WEGD4b8d+7THnf6n01?=

=?us-ascii?Q?uUG6zH3n1Ka5BpS5ORePwuTaSHNQE787Ki5cHVW955l5wrinuPT/Hoz3jLBj?=

=?us-ascii?Q?fn0sceOHPa5h/26DdN6mIKBAusE7aCkR1eCLgUVpeibwQsP+Am7regCfbO1l?=

=?us-ascii?Q?S0U8SsShMek5mGM7tC0t4yWzZKmkNFsT37gZkGYSE0yo3IZy8TozZiv0np/j?=

=?us-ascii?Q?Y49W5x7YZoI6PefhW78viLznsu3IS6zG1AHgu10xUeSsj15hbv0+H6LAuaY2?=

=?us-ascii?Q?QGHuQu8Z0BnOE1VCp+1iNVqbdjMoepsu8iq/4U9pa/GJycka+TMZk6wUMW1H?=

=?us-ascii?Q?9AoIou9bnc3sshKDKFGq+EO3RC4O0MuwH11E7EEGQL8q9Pl0eDxqO293jxAF?=

=?us-ascii?Q?/j4AAp778vUdrzPEpHWliMxq4ve/xk+tX+Qfpj/O3weSIPJ5GZbLyxfM/dYL?=

=?us-ascii?Q?h39lih91PMYRhKrYHQH1r8+ZGotQ5iDmrZjmT7b7UtJTeheustEobeoIoUs7?=

=?us-ascii?Q?Y6Bg02DK6D7236pVmKmP1b0gsuvC3O1cSz0LkLCczB4DfphXpVc8fa6iyaoh?=

=?us-ascii?Q?zeU8aEKAA+D6O5JJqdBXRTAHcjEiYGUUj4XJSPt8ULsHTU945fZvnUXxFBnV?=

=?us-ascii?Q?3Rr4yGQ6LPfHGs64btf+SwrUh/mJEczdOV2xir4koEMpFfPMteXkiPPxUOjn?=

=?us-ascii?Q?90RY95W5QjT9bpeEKJbSusmmmcw04rjCLoCj3xAZWHmURxgBKyOplRJdGIA7?=

=?us-ascii?Q?9tkkE+Yyy0yAZlJeGTIZ7MpoZucgpAlUq5rK+DrSiw/l2JBuNAa3DnfLZNgv?=

=?us-ascii?Q?RNZzJ3ZXrW+bQUUydJVaOeucPbUy+oSMnt4Rl4IE97Xw7nUg0bSgcqYc17aQ?=

=?us-ascii?Q?/8YcHi3sV9+pOq26VfS5TPmVJ57uPqWkGCjtx6za4WbK41zKHdMND9xLa1Ta?=

=?us-ascii?Q?/7Qwi/5CbgDdJjLc+zP+P0q3d4/dVwOLTe2Uxx/xmRUCFmvTnj7tHfLM4LLG?=

=?us-ascii?Q?WM14Hqz4/g=3D=3D?
```

Comment: We don't do log analysis. And most of what you posted isn't relevant to the IP. What you want to do if you want the header analysed is to use a header analyser like https://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx

Comment: I did, obviously, before posting, checked in multiple header analysis sites. Also checked every number in there that remotely looks like ip. Wanted to make sure there's not something that I don't know and somehow location can still be found from this header. Very important for me, I messed up and sent an email without vpn

Comment: We are not going to be able to do better than an email header analysis tool.